# Keep a Workbook open after a VBA Save to another file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that is updated from an external source. The code works but it closes both the Source Workbook and the New Workbook. How do I edit my code to keep the Source Workbook open?
Here is the code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("A2:Q2")
    If Not Intersect(target, Range("A2:Q2")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String
path = "C:\Users\rafin\"
filename1 = Range("G2") & Range("A2").Text
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove `ActiveWorkbook.Close`?

Comment: Thank your for helping.  Removing that line of code keeps the new (save as) workbook open. But I want that to remain closed and the Original (Source) workbook to remain open.

Comment: This question has pretty much been answered (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899824/how-to-use-vba-saveas-without-closing-calling-workbook ). However in your case, you can probably just use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.SaveCopyAs

Comment: Hi I was able to get what I need by removing Activeworkbook.close and adding this to my code:                                                                       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\rafin\Rafina code test2 4-1.xlsm", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False